# Outlook 2010 email

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I am in dispute about the time I have allegedly opened an email.
I actually opened it 6 days after it was sent/delivered to my inbox & checked the "read receipt" after reading.
But the sender is insisting tha I read it on the day it was sent.

Is it possible for me to prove when I actually opened it within my inbox? I can then send this proof & get me off the hook.

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

Kind Regards
Philip